# Docker - connect to host Postgres raises: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:5432: bind: address already in use

Tags: python, linux, postgresql, docker, debian

I'm fairly new to `Docker` and I'm trying to create a Django development container. I have `Postgres` database running on my PC on port `5432`.

I run this command:

```
docker run --env-file .env.dev -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 test sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate"
```

Which returns:

```
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:5432: bind: address already in use.
```

I understand that host port `5432` is already in use by `Postgres` but AFAIK I should map dockers `5432` to `5432` to be able to connect to the database, shouldn't I?

Comment: The `-p` option is for accepting connections _into_ your container; so if you were running a `postgres:13` container, for example.  You don't need a special option to make connections _out_ of your container.  (I marked this as a duplicate of the canonical question for this error message, but also see [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) to connect to a non-Docker database on the same host.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried  --network="host" when running container and it says: django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?